# Brother DCP-T510w prints, but don't scan, Ubuntu 20.04, How can I make xsane recognise it?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, scanner, brother, xsane

I used my printer with ease back in Ubuntu 18.04, but I had to upgrade it. The System works fine and installed all drivers from DCP-T510w Brother's page. The Printer works fine, although sometimes I have to make some roundabout way to do it, but the scanner doesn't work. Document scanner and xsane doesn't recognize it.

I saw a dozen forums about similar problems, but they seemed complicated and without standard. None concerning Ubuntu 20.04.

Here are some information, I could gather about the drivers.

ScanImage and Brother drivers:

[image: screenshot of terminal output related to ScanImage and Brother drivers]

sane, find scan:

[image: screenshot of terminal output related to sane libraries, and the output of "scanimage -L"]

Answer (score 1):

I have a Brother MFC and ran into the same problem.
It's seems like the 20.04 upgrade replaced /etc/sane.d/dll.conf with a default file.

The following fixed it for me:
`sudo nano /etc/sane.d/dll.conf`
I added a line with *brother2* at the end of the file.
Judging from your recently added screenshots you should add a line *brother4* if it's not already there.

If that doesn't fix it for you do a
`diff /etc/sane.d/dll.conf /etc/sane.d/dll.conf.dpkg-old`
Then you'll see the difference between the old and the new file to change it accordingly.

Comment: Did you try `diff /etc/sane.d/dll.conf /etc/sane.d/dll.conf.dpkg-old` as suggested and if yes, what was the result?